# How to finish activity after getting back from uninstaller

Tags: android

I am uninstalling an application which has already been selected by user as `PackageName`.

```
Button UninstallButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uninstallbutton);
UninstallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + PackageName));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

After uninstalling, I need to finish my calling activity. I realize that I can simply do this by calling `finish()` in `onRestart()` method.

```
@Override
public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    finish();
}
```

But the problem is that the method will always be called. I only need to finish my calling activity when the focus gets back after uninstalling the application and not by any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just take one flag for uninstall application indication. when you uninstall package then indicate flag to True otherwise false and in on restart

```
@Override
public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
     if(flag==true){
         finish();
         flag=false;
     }
}

Thats it...
```

Comment: What if the uninstall was cancelled? This would still finish the activity.

Comment: In That case just check package is available in device or not. Using PackageManager  you can check this. Than take decision.